# Getting 403 forbidden when Exporting API from WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have deployed the "API Export Import" war file in my wso2 api manager. After that, when I tried to export the API using the curl command, I'm getting 403 forbidden error with message "Unexpected token U". I'm facing this error only in the server but, in my local machine its working fine without any issues.

Note: In my server, im using WSO2 Identity Server as the key manager but, in my local i'm not using Identity server.

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: Do you see any errors on Console?